# VisualSVN Server self-signed certificate

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I'm reading VisualSVN doc online and one of them is like this:

```
It's also possible to export a self-signed certificate from VisualSVN Server and save this certificate in the trusted certificates list on all client computers.
```

But cannot find more info about how to do that.  Anybody can help me? I'm learning how to use SVN and will share with my brothers first.

**EDIT:**

We are using Windows machines: XP, Vista and 7.

Comment: Interesting question - I can't see any function to export the certificate. This may be better suited on Serverfault though - voting to migrate

Comment: I started bounty about exporting the certificate including private key. However the original question and both answers supplied was only about public part of the certificate. I later figured out how to get the full certificate, and posted this as answer here. My apologies to whoever found this inappropriate and downvoted it: I deleted it now. Next time I'll be more careful and start another question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it via your browser. When you open your VisualSVN Server URL using HTTPS, if your VisualSVN Server has self-signed certificate, browser will warn you about it. Browser will ask: would you add this certificate to the security exception list? If you will accept it, browser will add this certificate to the exception list and next time you visit this server you will connect without certificate confirmation.

As also you can export certificate via browser. For example, when you're trying to connect to the server with self-signed certificate using Firefox, it will show you "This Connection is Untrusted" message. You can export certificate with the following steps:

1. Choose "I understand the risk"
2. Click "Add Exception" button. "Add Security Exception" window will be open.
3. After a few seconds "view" button will be active, click it. "Certificate viewer" window will be open.
4. Choose "Details" tab and then click "export".
5. Firefox will offer you to save certificate on your local disk. You'll be able to choose the format of the certificate before saving. After you get the certificate you'll be able to import it everywhere you want.

As you have noticed, VisualSVN Server Manager doesn't support export of the certificates. But this function will be supported in one of the next releases.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a problem with self-signed certificates and found a way to accept them permanently for my build user on my build server.

From the command-line call svn as:

```
svn.exe list https://YOURsvnhost:YOURport/svn/YOURproject
```

you will be promted with an option to accept the certificate permanently